# Unit Testing Routed Events in WPF

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am creating an MVVM WPF application. In my unit tests, it seems I am being forced to register a whole piles of RoutedEventArgs to pass to my VM commands when testing. While I don't see any real problem with this so far, I imagine it would be better to leave the WPF framework out of my unit tests, a la Clean Coding. I tried mocking the event args, but the WPF framework complains about the Event Args not being registered. I am using MVVM Light as well.

Question is this: Is there any way to mock a RoutedEventArgs for use in unit testing? Can you suggest a different way to do it?

Comment: When we can't easily mock out Microsoft objects, we get what we need and pass it into another function that can be easily tested.
private void WhateverCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) { DoSomething(e.Parameter); }

Comment: Good idea. What are your thoughts on the rule to never change your code for unit testing as it applies to that technique?

Comment: I think it's rather impossible.  You'll eventually encounter some functionality in 3rd party code that's impossible to mock, so you'll throw it in a mockable virtual function that just returns what you need.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you submit an answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We follow more of a model-view-presenter format in our WPF applications, but we get what we need on the command CanExecute and Executed functions, then pass it into our testable presentation layer.  You can use a similar technique:

```cs
private void WhateverCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {   
    DoSomething(e.Parameter); 
}
```